# Burning out relays when supposed to be within ratings

Tags: transistors, relay, raspberry-pi, troubleshooting

I am using this Normally Closed Relay on a 24V circuit: [DataSheet](http://cotorelay.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/9000_series_reed_relay_datasheet.pdf)

The circuit is 24VDC source, which I measured the Amperage in series to be 29mA at the highest. I've breadboarded a lower voltage circuit (5V) fine with the relay. When I put the relay into the 24VDC circuit, I am able to open and close the circuit one time, but it burns out the relay: the relay can never be switched open again. I notice when switching it under the 24V load that when I close the switch again, it delays before completing the circuit.

For the switched circuit: I have 24VDC source connected to pin 1 of the Relay, and the rest of the circuit connected to pin 4 which is connected to a the magnetic door lock (and a push to exit button, which may use a capacitor to trigger the 30 second open circuit)

For the switching circuit: I have 5VDC from a Raspberry Pi connected to pin 2. On pin 3, I have it connected to the Collector side of an NPN relay, and the Emitter side is connected to a Ground pin on the Raspberry Pi. I have one of the GPIO pins connected to a 2kΩ resistor, which is then connected to the base of the relay

[Reference circuit I used for my circuit is here](https://www.openhomeautomation.net/control-a-relay-from-anywhere-using-the-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: What kind of load are you switching? And please clarify, the relay COIL is still good, but the CONTACTS are welded shut?

Comment: Double check if you have kept the NC terminal of the relay open it should not be grounded. Made this mistake myself.

Comment: If your load is inductive, you should put a flyback diode across it.

Comment: @RDrast: How can I verify if the the coil vs the contacts? It is no longer making the audible switching sound when the voltage is applied to the coil. The load is 24VDC, and the amperage is never above 29mA when the relay was not connected

Comment: I'm talking about the flyback diode across the load, not the one across the relay coil (which is also necessary).  What type of load is it, and what type of diode was across it?

Comment: @JohnD I only had one across the coil, a 1n4148. Been a bit since I did some EE, how can I tell the type of load I am dealing with?

Comment: Just tell us what the load is. Is it an electronic circuit board, a motor, a heater, a lightbulb? What is it?

Comment: It's a magnetic door lock

Comment: A magnetic door lock is an inductive solenoid

Comment: @DanMcClain If the contacts weld shut, they will still read closed when coil power is removed.  The coil can be checked with an ohmmeter as well, all the coil resistances for all of your relays should be pretty close to the same (if they are the same type); check against a known good one.  To save the contacts, it is customary to put flyback diode or snubber circuit in parallel with them.  For a diode, you are going to want one beefier than an 4148, try a 1n4004 or 4008.

Comment: @RDrast Thanks, this is a normally closed relay, but I was able to resurrect it by tapping it on the table, so it seems as though it was welded shut (Don't worry, I'm going to scrap that relay). Would something like this SSR work for my application? http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/CPC1916Y/CLA209-ND/654909

Answer (score 4):

If your switched circuit contains some kind of capacitor, motor or tungsten light bulb you could easily be exceeding the contact ratings (500mA maximum) momentarily.

For example, if the load has a capacitor inside, the circuit looks very much like a capacitive discharge welder, with the materials to be welded the contacts in your relay. Once they are welded together, they are damaged and you should discard the relay, though you may be able to free them up temporarily by tapping the relay.

Edit: Switching a door lock solenoid can also cause welding by arcing when the relay drops out or bounces. If the solenoid is less than 500mA (6W) you may be able to make this work by adding a catch diode such as a 1N4004 across the solenoid, but generally this kind of relay is not great for switching relatively heavy loads. You'd be better off to use a power relay or a transistor such as MOSFET (always with the catch diode).

Comment: I've been able to "revive" the relay by tapping it, so it seems like it welded the contacts together

Comment: Would I wire the MOSFET on the ground side of the door lock, to interrupt it from grounding, and that way it would ground to that circuit, and not the Raspberry pi. I assume that voltage grounding to the Pi's ground would blow it up, right?